# RoR: instances variables within controller methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coding-style

My question is about controller methods (possibly included from an outside class) that work with instance variables. I frequently use a before_filter in controllers to set up certain variables, e.g.:

```
class DocumentController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :fetch_document

  def action
    @document.do_something
  end

  private

  def fetch_document
    @document = Document.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

I've been working on a project in which a few controllers will share some functionality, say, document editing.  My first thought was to extract the relevant methods, and get them from application_controller.rb or a separate module.  But then I noticed I was writing code that looks like this:

```
  def fetch_document
    @document = Document.find(params[:id])
  end

  def do_something_to_document
    @document.do_something
  end
```

This sets off warning bells: do_something_to_document is essentially assuming the existence of @document, rather than taking it as an argument.  Is this, in your sage opinions, a bad coding practice?  Or am I being paranoid?

Assuming it is an issue, I see two general approaches to deal with it:

1. Check for the instance var and bail unless it's set:

   ```
   def do_something_to_document
     raise "no doc!" unless @document
     [...]
   end
   ```
2. Call the action with the instance var as an argument:

   ```
   def do_something_to_document(document)
     [...]
   end
   ```

2 looks better, because it hides the context of the calling object.  But do_something_to_doc will only be called by controllers that have already set up @document, and taking @document as a method argument incurs the overhead of object creation.  (Right?) 1 seems hackish, but should cover all of the cases.

I'm inclined to go with 1 (assuming I'm right about the performance issue), even though seeing a list of methods referencing mysterious instance vars gives me hives.  Thoughts?  Let me know if I can be more clear.  (And of course, if this is answered somewhere I didn't see it, just point me in the right direction...)

Thanks,
-Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need document in different controllers, I'd do something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  private
  def document
    @document ||= Document.find(params[:document_id])
  end
end

class FooController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :ensure_document, :only => [:foo]

  def foo
    document.do_something
  end

  private
  # TODO: not sure if controller_name/action_name still exists
  def ensure_document
    raise "#{controller_name}##{action_name} needs a document" unless document
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks.  I like this approach.

Comment: Just noticed: the ensure_document will never be executed here. document wont be nil, cause find() would raise an error if nothing was found.

Comment: Yep.  General idea holds, though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @variable are session/instance variable you will get a Nil exception in **do_something_to_document** method.

The first code is fine, because **before_filter** will always load your @document.

I suggest you to write something like that

```
def fetch_document(doc_id)
  @document ||= Document.find(doc_id)
end

def do_something_to_document
  my_doc = fetch_document(params[:id])
end
```

where **do_something_to_document** is in the controller (if not, dont use params[:id], even if you know you can access this global, use another explicit parameter). The ||= thing, will asssure that you call the base only once by request.

Comment: `@document ||= Document.find(doc_id)`

Doing this kind of caching with passing arguments can be very tricky.
It will always return the same @document during request, even if "doc_id" changes.